# How to access a specific variable created inside a function outside a function. Even when there are multiple other variables in that function

Tags: python, function

I am new to programming and I am trying to teach myself. I am starting with python and I am struggling to figure out if I am going about this the right way. I am trying to figure out how to access a specific variable from inside a function outside of that function.

```
weight = input('Enter Amount: ')

def quantity():
  p_total = weight / 454
  print(f'Amount: {p_total}')
  
  hp_total = weight / 227
  print(f'Amount HP: {hp_total}')
  
  qp_total = weight / 114
  print(f'Amount QP: {qp_total}')

  return p_total, hp_total, qp_total

print(qp_total)
```

I want to then be able to access the individual variables created in there as needed. Such as being able to call just qp_total or p_total. Or would this not be a good use of a function? Again I am still extremely new to coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your result is a tuple, you can provide an index to retrieve the item you want from that tuple:

```py
def quantity(weight):
    p_total = weight / 454
    hp_total = weight / 227
    qp_total = weight / 114
    return p_total, hp_total, qp_total

print(quantity(50)[2]) # 0.43859649122807015
```

If you want to have multiple items, but not the whole result, then you may use `_` for the "empty" output (although technically not really "empty"):

```py
p_total, _, qp_total = quantity(50)
print(p_total, qp_total) # 0.11013215859030837 0.43859649122807015
```

---

A concept like "accessing internal variables from outside" sounds more like pertaining to "class":

```py
class Quantity():
    def __init__(self, weight):
        self.p_total = weight / 454
        self.hp_total = weight / 227
        self.qp_total = weight / 114

q = Quantity(50)
print(q.qp_total) # 0.43859649122807015
```

But in my opinion, it is an overcomplication in this case.

Comment: Thank you for this. I really may just start learning about Classes on my own. I feel like since I am new and haven't even learned classes yet that a lot of my code is over complicated at the moment. I just feel like the stuff they are teaching in the class rooms is so slow and they are not going to teach us enough since we are already halfway through the semester and just learned how to make a list. But again thanks for your response.

Comment: @Rhyez Glad it helped! I am not blaming your code or approach. In my humble opinion overcomplication for the sake of practice is sometimes (or often) useful and helpful when it comes to learning new concepts :) In high school, as a non-native speaker, I used be required to make convoluted English sentences, but that's part of learning, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You never actually call your quantity function. Plus you should really pass the weight variable in:

```py
def quantity(weight):
  p_total = weight / 454
  print(f'Amount: {p_total}')
  
  hp_total = weight / 227
  print(f'Amount HP: {hp_total}')
  
  qp_total = weight / 114
  print(f'Amount QP: {qp_total}')

  return p_total, hp_total, qp_total

weight = input('Enter Amount: ')
p_total, hp_total, qp_total = quantity(weight)
print(qp_total)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def quantity(weight):
  p_total = weight / 454
  hp_total = weight / 227
  qp_total = weight / 114
  return p_total, hp_total, qp_total

weight = int(input('Enter Amount: '))
p_total = quantity(weight)[0]
hp_total = quantity(weight)[1]
qp_total = quantity(weight)[2]
print(qp_total)
```

The weight input must be converted to an integer because in python the input is passed as a string.

Comment: Your right. Thanks for that! :)